# Align/scale controls relative to background image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm having a hard time with fulfilling the following requirement.

I've been tasked to create a user control in WPF that can be hosted into a windows forms application.

I need to line up controls (text boxes) with a background image.  The user must be able to adjust the window size, or zoom in or out of the control, and the text boxes must adjust their size to remain relative to the background image.

For example, consider the following screen shot:

[image]

I need the two boxes to stay in the same position relative to the chart image.  Currently, if I expand the user control's size, I get something like this:

[image]

My XAML is the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="444" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" Width="834">

    <Grid Name="MyGrid">
        <Image Name="MyImage" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Source="/ParklandCounty.Dynamics.AX.CANT4;component/Resources/Chart.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

        <TextBox x:Name="txt14Dollars" Margin="558,78,111,310" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="BOX 1" Background="Transparent" TextAlignment="Right" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="#FF0524F9"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt15Dollars" Margin="579,144,90,244" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="BOX 2" Background="Transparent" TextAlignment="Right" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="#FF0524F9"/>

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

EDIT:

Some more detail on the end result I want.  Hopefully the following mockup explains what I want:

Essentially the user control will be hosted in an existing windows forms application.  There will be a form as an image that will displayed as the background of the control.  I need to "overlay" my own text boxes over the form, so they line up with the existing form text boxes.

If the user re-sizes the parent window, the user control will expand or contract accordingly, thus increasing or decreasing the dimensions of the image.

The wpf text controls should remain in the relative position and size to the form image.

[image]

Comment: I'd bet it's things like `Margin="558,78,111,310"` that are making the garbage result. Do you have a better visual example of what you're after? I should have time to whip you out an example pretty quick I'm just having trouble visualizing what you're really after.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I've edited the original question to provide more detail.

Comment: Aaaah, ok so after seeing that I'm glad I got a little visualization from you. I thought you were just trying trying to keep points on a required image, not just floating inputs over a form picture. In which case my question would be why do it this way? Is it some sort of requirement? You could lay out the form to look exactly the same in reliable xaml without the background image, at least that's how I would do it. For this specific of an issue if the image is required as background I'd probably need the actual image to tinker for a minute with min/max values etc to fit correct.

Comment: Essentially this is a government form, that has complex layout.  We only need to modify certain information on the form, and the form layout may change from year to year.  Reproducing the form in it's entirety would be overkill in my opinion.

Comment: Yea I've dealt with those HEAVILY. We found out it's easier to visually reproduce the form in pure xaml than it was to just use a scanned image as a backdrop. Made changes so much faster/easier and you could handle any resizing or ommission/adding of visible elements smoothly. Of course how strong your xaml skills are can be a factor though.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  My XAML is poor, hence the above question =)

Comment: If you genuinely have the only option of using the image. Set it as your Grid's background via ImageBrush like `<Grid><Grid.Backgroun><ImageBrush ImageSource="/Project;component/Images/image.png"/></Grid.Background></Grid>` and setup your rows/columns to mimic the layout of the form entirely but using relative spacing/sizing on elements and rows/columns and it will resize reasonably well from there. However I would still suggest my route to avoid weird fuzzy resolutions and stuff with your image getting stretched around like that.